# Pre-trained text classifier to check whether a document is business or personal

Tags: data, machine-learning-model, llm

I need a pre-trained classifier that checks if a document is either a business or personal document. I don't have time to train one myself so if anyone knows of a classifier that is pre-trained and they think it's good, please let me know.

Here is an example of a document it would have to classify: # Relationship Notes

### With Alex (Partner)

#### Date Ideas

- [ ] Plan a romantic weekend getaway to the mountains.

  - Alex loves the mountains. It's been a while since our last escape to nature. ️❤️
- [ ] Surprise Alex with tickets to his favorite band's concert.

  - Found out they're coming to town next month. It'll be a great surprise!
- [ ] Cook a special dinner together and have a movie night at home.

  - Sometimes, the simplest evenings are the most memorable. ️
- [ ] Organize a picnic in the park for a relaxing day outdoors.

  - We used to do this a lot when we started dating. Time to bring back those moments. ☀️
- [ ] Write heartfelt love letters to each other on our anniversary.

  - It's our 5th anniversary next week. A handwritten letter can express so much.

#### Vacation Plans

- [ ] Research and book our next international adventure.

  - Thinking about Greece or Costa Rica. We both need a break from work. ✈️️
- [ ] Discuss potential travel destinations for our summer vacation.

  - We have conflicting ideas. Need to sit down and find a destination that excites both of us. ️
- [ ] Create a shared calendar to coordinate our schedules better.

  - Our schedules have been chaotic lately. A shared calendar might help us plan quality time together. ️❤️